# How do I publish my ASP.NET Web API 2 project to IIS 8.5 using Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, asp.net-web-api, deployment

I have an ASP.NET Web API 2 project that compiles and works as expected on my local machine, but when I publish to my IIS 8.5 server, all my requests just come back with status code 500 server error. No additional information is given. This is my first time attempting to publish a Web API.

I have made a site in IIS, configured it the same as other sites I've made, and set it to HTTPS only. I believe the site is configured correctly because I have a basic default.html page that I can easily connect to, but I just can't seem to make any API calls. I'm using Postman to test my API calls.

In Visual Studio, I've used **Web Deploy**, **Web Deploy Package** and **File System Publish** options. Using the "Precompile during publishing" option for the latter two does not appear to make a difference.

**Web Deploy** refuses to validate the connection, saying that it can't connect to the remote computer and to make sure Web Deploy is installed. I can verify it is through "Programs and Features", and I've tried just about every combination of URI I can think of to get it to connect with no avail. The error directs me to this [Microsoft troubleshooting page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/troubleshooting-web-deploy/web-deploy-error-codes#ERROR_DESTINATION_NOT_REACHABLE), but the commands suggested don't seem to work.

**Web Deploy Package** allows me to create a .zip on my local file system which I then transfer to the hosting server and import using Web Deploy from IIS. The screenshot below is what I see in the IIS website's root directory after import. I manually add the HTML file for testing as it's not part of my application. The bin folder appears to contain all the necessary DLL files.

[image: Web API IIS website file structure]

**File System Publish** outputs the same structure as Web Deploy Package, with no difference in behavior.

Is there something I've been missing? I just don't know what else to troubleshoot.

Comment: Something is crashing your application's runtime. The easiest way to troubleshoot is inspecting the message of 500-response. If an appropriate errorDetailsPolicy was chosen for your application, the message will contain description about occured exception. Here is an example how to enable detailed errors in web API: https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/04/18/custom-errors-and-error-detail-policy-in-asp-net-web-api/

Comment: I was unaware that Web API didn't respect the web.config customErrors rule. With that I was able to solve the problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To repeat [@n.piskunov's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47783620/how-do-i-publish-my-asp-net-web-api-2-project-to-iis-8-5-using-visual-studio-201?noredirect=1#comment82539815_47783620), my app did not have any error details policy. This article by [Jimmy Bogard](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2012/04/18/custom-errors-and-error-detail-policy-in-asp-net-web-api/) explains that Web API doesn't respect the `web.config` file's `customErrors` setting, which is what I was using. It also explains how to fix said issue.

With detailed error messages enabled, I was able to figure out that the target framework was not installed on the server. Installing the correct target framework solved my issue.

Comment: Yes, that's a really confusing issue with customErrors in Web API applications. The most weird is that, accordingly to MS docs , IncludeErrorDetailPolicy by default is pointing to customErrors mode value. But, in fact, it isn't, when you are using Owin.Webhost (it is pointing to LocalOnly policy in this case). So, if you wan't to manage error details reporting in Web API applications, you have to set IncludeErrorDetailPolicy  manually.